# Fotorama image margins with the Montezuma theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fotorama

I am using the Montezuma WordPress theme, which sets up margins on images, and this affects Fotorama galleries in an unwanted way (images are shifted down and rightwards without extending the image area). As an example, you can look at http://larsjaas.no-ip.org/index.php/2013/09/hiking-in-femundsmarka/

Fotorama seems to depend on certain margins (borders?) being 0 pixels, but does not seem to override them when instantiated. Any hints on where to adjust the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this somewhere in your styles:

```
.fotorama__img {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```